# IE Bug - Trying to get width/height of image and give it margin-top and margin-left

Tags: jquery, css

I have this code at the bottom of my page to center some images proportionally on a page. It works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but it doesn't in IE. It does execute the `fadeIn(2000);` in IE but it won't move the images. Is this an IE bug? Any suggestions?

```
    <script>
        jQuery.noConflict();
        $j(window).load(
function () {

    $j('#featured img').each(
    function () {
        var theWidth = $j(this).width();
        var theHeight = $j(this).height();

        $j(this).css({ 'margin-top': -theHeight / 2 + 'px', 
                       'margin-left': -theWidth / 2 + 'px' });
    });
    $j("#featured img").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

**Edit**

```
 <div id="featured"><a href="mysite.com" target="_blank"><img src="myimage.jpg" id="Image38" /></a></div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div style="background-color: #e4e4e4; margin-top: 20px;">
    <div id="featured"><a href="mysite.com" target="_blank"><img src="myimage.gif" id="Image1" /></a></div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div id="featured"><img src="myimage.jpg" id="Image2"  /></div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Comment: Are you getting back the expected values for `theWidth` and `theHeight`?

Comment: I just looked in the IE debugger and it says undefined for theWidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work fine for me, in both IE/FF/CHROME... see: http://jsfiddle.net/2QCFM/

```
$('#featured img').each(
function () {
    var theWidth = $(this).width();
    var theHeight = $(this).height();

    $(this).css({ 'margin-top': -theHeight / 2 + 'px',
                   'margin-left': -theWidth / 2 + 'px' });
    alert('width:' + theWidth + ' height:'+ theHeight);
});
$("#featured img").fadeIn(2000);
```

Comment: Ok I added the alert to see if I was getting any values. It works fine in FF/Chrome, but in IE it only does the first image. I only got one alert box. I have about 15 images on that page. Ideas?

Comment: See this: http://jsfiddle.net/2QCFM/2/ - dosen't that work for you? Maybe it's some other JS that interferes with it. Could you paste your html for the images?

Comment: Yes, I tested that in jsfiddle and it worked fine for me. I added some html samples in my request.

Comment: Argh, now i see the problem. You can only have ONE id with the same name. So Internet Explore sees the first <div id="featured"> and skips over the rest - so rename them to a class or something :)

Answer (score 0):

> I just looked in the IE debugger and it says undefined for theWidth.

That *sounds like* the `.load()` event is firing prematurely, before the targeted image has been loaded.  I had all kinds of problems getting this to work reliably with IE.

I discovered that if an image is set to `display:none;`, the `.load()` event in IE seems to ignore it entirely.  To IE, `display:none` means the image does not exist as far as the `load()` event is concerned.

I can't see your CSS code but since you're doing a `fadeIn()`, I can only assume you have the image set to `display:none` in the CSS.

I fixed my IE situation by removing `display:none` from the CSS and setting it within jQuery immediately after the `.load()` event, with a `.css({'display':'none'})`.

Try this, (but you may have to play around with where you want to do your `.css({'display':'none'})`):

```
$j(window).load(function () {
    $j('#featured img').css({'display':'none'}); // <- set within jQ instead of CSS so IE can see image upon initial window.load().
    $j('#featured img').each(function () {

        function () {
            var theWidth = $j(this).width();
            var theHeight = $j(this).height();

            $j(this).css({ 'margin-top': -theHeight / 2 + 'px', 
                           'margin-left': -theWidth / 2 + 'px' });
     });
     $j("#featured img").fadeIn(2000);
});
```